# Find conditions for $a$ and $b$ such that $P(x)=x^4-(a+b)x^3+(ab+2)x^2-(a+b)x+1$ has only real roots.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

I need to find conditions for *a* and *b* such that $$P(x)=x^4-(a+b)x^3+(ab+2)x^2-(a+b)x+1$$ has only real roots.
Any hints on how I should do that?

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT :

$$x^4-(a+b)x^3+(ab+2)x^2-(a+b)x+1=(x^2-ax+1)(x^2-bx+1)$$

Comment: Using this equality, I get that $a,b∈(-∞,-2]U[2,∞)$. Is that right?

Comment: @FrancieleDaltoé : Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful o/

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** You have a palindromic polynomial, hence $P(x)=0$ is equivalent to:

$$ \left(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)-(a+b)\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)+(ab+2) = 0\tag{1} $$
or, by setting $z=x+\frac{1}{x}$,
$$ z^2-(a+b)z+ab = (z-a)(z-b) = 0.\tag{2} $$
Consider now that the range of $f(x)=x+\frac{1}{x}$ is $\mathbb{R}\setminus(-2,2)$.